# Materialize 1.0 checkbox does not render as expected

Tags: html, materialize

I'd need to insert a checkbox in my code by using the Materialize css library.

My html

```
<head>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<main>   
  <div class="container " style="padding-left: 2vw;">
    <div class="params_container">
    <form action="#">
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="test9" />
        <label for="test9">Red</label>
      </p>
    </form>
  </div><!-- params_container -->
 </div>
</main>
```

This code just shows the label text "`Red`" and no checkbox.

I've read in other posts that in Materialize css v. 1.0.0 the checkbox shows only by using `<span>Red</span>` and not `<label>Red </label>`. With `<span>` the checkbox does render indeed but it can't be checked if clicked.

Does any of you know what I'm missing?

Comment: I tried your code in codepen. It's working fine with `<label>`

Comment: I don't know why in my code it does not

Comment: Check here https://codepen.io/shashank_gb/pen/rNjgdmV

Comment: I see.. probably some conflicts, I do not have other ideas. Thank you for your time